# Native Azure Mobile Service (C++) Crashes When Disconnected

Tags: c++, azure, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I have a native WinRT app that using Azure Mobile for its backend. It works great so long as it can reach the service. If the internet is disconnected, any queries will crash the app with no warning or place to catch the exception, as the crash happens in an async call. Here's the minimum code I've found that reproduces the issue:

```
azure::mobile::client c(L"https://MYSERVICE.azure-mobile.net/", L"MYKEY");
azure::mobile::table table(c, L"MYTABLE");
table.read(); // Adding any .then continuation also leads to exception
```

And here's the exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x018DCFF6 (msvcr120d_app.dll) in : An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

If I'm supposed to detect connectivity using the azure mobile API before making any queries, I can't find any way to do that. I don't think simply checking internet connectivity is a sufficient answer, and I would also think pinging the service manually before making any queries is a unnecessarily obtuse way to detect an error. It seems like the query results are supposed to come back empty if there was an error, but the code never gets that far. Am I missing something?

**Update**: It seems the app will also crash if I successfully connect to the service but the table hasn't been created. Again, there is no ability to detect this scenario using the API that I can find.

Comment: Not that this will directly help, but I see the same thing using `HttpClient` with a normal Windows 8.1 C# app (that when connectivity drops, the app crashes with an unrecoverable error). I wonder if the Azure C++ classes use the same framework components for connectivity.

Comment: How do you work around that in C#?

Comment: I haven't found a good way yet. I can consistently crash the app with ease. :( I'm trying a new communication option in Windows 10, which won't help you unfortunately.

Comment: I tried reproducing you issue and I couldn't pull it off. Maybe open a question on your issue, we can get to the bottom of that, and perhaps it will lead to an answer to mine?